# Puppeteer doesn't work in AWS, expects selector but won't find it

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, jenkins, puppeteer

Puppeteer works correctly in my locale, but when I deploy this code to the AWS server, it waits for the selector for 30 seconds, and does not find it. This happens when I use a proxy server.

Here is my code

```
        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

        await page.waitForSelector('.upay-manager-card-add');
        await page.click('.upay-manager-card-add');

        await page.waitForTimeout(2000);

        try {
            await page.waitForSelector('.arco-radio-mask');
            await page.click('.arco-radio-mask');
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('ERROR Selector - ', e);
        }


        await page.waitForTimeout(2000);
```

And it's my fault.

```
ERROR Selector -  TimeoutError: Waiting for selector `.arco-radio-mask` failed: Waiting failed: 30000ms exceeded
at Timeout.<anonymous> (/var/www/dolphin/dolphin-cloud-scrapper/node_modules/puppeteer-core/src/common/WaitTask.ts:79:11)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
at processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)
```